# logistic regression ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [699,

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm new to Python and trying to perform linear regression using sklearn on a pandas dataframe. This is what I did:

first i label my data frame

```
  # imports
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

col=['Id','Clump Thickness','Uniformity of Cell Size','Uniformity of Cell Shape','Marginal Adhesion',
                            'Single Epithelial Cell Size','Bare Nuclei','Bland Chromatin','Normal Nucleoli','Mitoses','Class']
# read data into a DataFrame
data = pd.read_csv("breast_cancer.txt",header=None, prefix="V")
data.columns = col
d = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=col)
```

second i filled all missing values with mean of corresponding feature

```
list_of_means = d.mean()

# filling missing values with mean 
for i in range (2,10):
    for j in range(699):
        if d.iloc[j, i] == "?":
            d.iloc[j, i] = round(list_of_means[i],0)
d['Type'] = 'benign'
# map Type to 0 if class is 2 and 1 if class is 4 
d['Type'] = d.Class.map({2:0, 4:1})
X = d[['Clump Thickness','Uniformity of Cell Size','Uniformity of Cell Shape','Marginal Adhesion',
                            'Single Epithelial Cell Size','Bare Nuclei','Bland Chromatin','Normal Nucleoli','Mitoses']]
```

third i created new column and named Type to map class 2 to type 0 and class 4 to type 1

```
y=[['Type']]
# instantiate a logistic regression model, and fit with X and y
model = LogisticRegression()
model = model.fit(X.reshape(X.shape[0], 1), y)
# check the accuracy on the training set
score = model.score(X, y)
#calculate correlation matrix
corMat = DataFrame(data.iloc[:,2:10].corr())
print 'correlation matrix'
print(corMat)

print score

print X.head()
```

however i am getting this error 
**logistic regression ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples:** 
and after i did some search i found out that sklearn requires the data shape of (row number, column number) so fit method to

```
model = model.fit(X.reshape(X.shape[0], 1), y)
```

as you seeing above but i am getting new error says

**return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'reshape'**

data set features

```
 #  Attribute                     Domain
   -- -----------------------------------------
   1. Sample code number            id number
   2. Clump Thickness               1 - 10
   3. Uniformity of Cell Size       1 - 10
   4. Uniformity of Cell Shape      1 - 10
   5. Marginal Adhesion             1 - 10
   6. Single Epithelial Cell Size   1 - 10
   7. Bare Nuclei                   1 - 10
   8. Bland Chromatin               1 - 10
   9. Normal Nucleoli               1 - 10
  10. Mitoses                       1 - 10
  11. Class:                        (2 for benign, 4 for malignant)
```

PS: I have noticed that a large number of beginner questions were down-voted in stackoverflow. Kindly take into account the fact that things that seem obvious to an expert user may take a beginner days to figure out. Please use discretion when pressing the down arrow you'd harm the vibrancy of this discussion community.

Comment: (1) if Class has values other than 2 and 4, there will be NaN for those after the mapping, you'd better get rid of them, (2) y=[['Type']] --> y=d[['Type']], (3) you don't need to reshape X.

Comment: @vpekar class has only have 2 and 4  here is link to data set http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/breast-cancer-wisconsin.data

Comment: Your code works fine is you correct the assignment of y (`y=d[['Type']]`) and fit the model like this: `model = LogisticRegression().fit(X, y)`. Also you should not evaluate on the training set.

Comment: @vpekar thanks for your help i missed assign y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my code was correct except that i had a typo when i am trying to assign 
y so i changed

```
y=[['Type']]
```

to

```
y=d[['Type']]
```

also note that scikit learn will throw warning because i am passing column vector instead of id array but you can solve this by change

```
model.fit(X, y) to 
model.fit(X, y.values.ravel())
```

**DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().
  y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)**